# Android: How to find which platform version an APK targets?

Tags: android

Given an APK, is it possible to determine which version of Android platform it targets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can extract the APK and look in the manifest file for the platform target.

Comment: The Manifest is not human readable after being compiled. You may have to use some tool to get the values out.

Comment: Any tools you might know?

Comment: you can use `aapt list`. see answer from @Sylvain

Comment: User this site http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool to decompile code

Comment: You can use already installed apkanalyzer tool to see the manifest in a human readable format. Just use: `apkanalyzer manifest print some.apk`

Answer (score 117):

Use `aapt`:

```
aapt list -a package.apk | grep SdkVersion
```

You will see version numbers in hex. e.g.:

```
  A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x3
  A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0xc
```

For this apk, `minSdkVersion` is `0x3` i.e. 3, and `targetSdkVersion` is `0xc` i.e. 12.

Comment: `aapt` is available in `sdk\build-tools\XX.X.X`.

Comment: @Thupten's answer says use `aapt dump badging` instead of `aapt list -a` which gives a more readable output.

Comment: is there a way to use this tool to find out what architecture is supported? ie. x86 or arm

Comment: To expand on Hirbod's comment. In Win10 I found aapt.exe in    
 \Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.3\     And of course in Windows "grep" changes to "findstr".

Comment: Note: with Android Studio 4.2 on macos, you can find the `sdk/build-tools/XXX` folder location (where the `aapt` tool lives) via Android Studio Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK. Mine gives: `/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: @neno in addition, `aapt dump badging` has the advantage to find the version numbers if they are used like this in AndroidManifest.xml: `<uses-sdk android:="26" android:="31" />`.

Answer (score 37):

Use [apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)

```
java -jar apktool.jar d app.apk
```

Then look in the generated apktool.yml file for this:

```
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: '11'
  targetSdkVersion: '17'
```

You can match the SDK version to Android version [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels). In the above example minimum Android version is 3.0 and target version is 4.2.

Comment: Thanks for the .yml tip.  I used apktool, looked in AndroidManifest.xml and was confused to discover that the info I wanted was missing!  Did not think to look in the .yml file.

Comment: Exactly as @ajh158 mentioned, confused. Thanks!

Comment: Note some apps display "sdkInfo: null" in apktool.yml but you can find the values in AndroidManifest.xml, for example as <uses-sdk android:="26" android:="31" />.

Answer (score 35):

simply use `aapt dump badging my_apk_file.apk` to get a lot of info about your apk.
grep filter by Version
`aapt dump badging my_apk_file.apk|grep Version`

Output with *$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools/30.0.3/aapt*:

```
package: name=... versionCode=... versionName=... compileSdkVersion='29' compileSdkVersionCodename='10'
sdkVersion:'11'
targetSdkVersion:'29'
```

The apk for any installed app `$app` (eg *com.google.android.apps.docs*) can be retrieved from your device with:

```
adb pull $(adb shell dumpsys package $app | grep path: | cut -c11-) $app.apk
```

Comment: sdkVersion means the minimum version, right? At least it looks like this because I got an error when installing and APK file that said I did not meet the minimum version requirement of API 26 and sdkVersion value was 26. The AndroidManifest.xml file also had <uses-sdk android:="26" android:="31" />.

Answer (score 16):

You can use apkanalyzer, it is  is included in the Android SDK Tools, more infos here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer

Prints the minimum SDK version.

```
apkanalyzer -h manifest min-sdk myapk.apk
```

Prints the target SDK version

```
apkanalyzer -h manifest target-sdk myapk.apk
```

Comment: It has GUI mode: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer

Answer (score 4):

like derek said above

use the [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to decompile the apk and check the manifest version

platform versions can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have grep, you can use

```
aapt list -a package.apk >file.txt
```

and search for minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in file.txt.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find these info from your mobile device you can install **My APK** app which gives you good information about apps
You can get it at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andatsoft.myapk.fwa&hl=en

The app which you want to have these information about, must either installed on your mobile device or you must have the app apk on your mobile.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to get APK information is to use this online tool :
https://www.sisik.eu/apk-tool

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I opened the apk file on Android Studio. So I can check the version of android at **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Answer (score 1):

if you want it programmatically try use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class:

```
public PackageManager getPackageArchiveInfo(String archiveFilePath, int flags)
```

then read  ApplicationInfo field and targetSdkVersion in it;

Answer (score 1):

You can run following command to just get the API level (integer):

```
aapt dump badging "your_apk.apk" | awk '/targetSdkVersion/{gsub("targetSdkVersion:''|''","");  print $1}'
```

The output you'll get will be as below, in case it was compiled against KitKat (API 19):

> 19

PS: aapt is located in folder `<Android-Sdk>/build-tools/<build-tools-version>/`.

Answer (score 1):

To find the platform targets for an APK file, use `apktool`.
Follow these instructions:

1. Use the GitHub repo to install it https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/.
2. After installing then run the following command -> `apktool` d file.apk
3. open the file folder.
4. locate the file named `apktool.yml`
5. the information is found in the SDK info:
   [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faKwR.jpg), [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drvc6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nautilus, you can add a column provider and a property page provider for APK files. This will provide lots of informations, including SdkVersion.

Steps are explained on this link : http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/76-gnome/324-gnome-nautilus-apk-column-property-provider-extension

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk to decomplier file apk and you can find it in Mandifest

Answer (score 0):

Another bush util function:

```
function android-target-sdk-version {
    aapt list -a $1 | grep targetSdkVersion | grep -o '....$' | awk '{print $1+0}'
}
```