# How does Android system find sdk info in app that installed on the phone?

Tags: android

I want to know which target the apk is aiming, I use apktool to decompile the apk file, but I can't find the sdk info in the decompiled apk files, but only in the **apktool.yml** file like this:

```
sdkInfo:  
  minSdkVersion: '14'  
  targetSdkVersion: '23'
```

I wonder where can Android system find the information in the apk that installed in the phone? Why I can't find the information in the decompiled files?

---

update:

There are suspicious information in decompiled `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but there are consistent with the information in the `apktool.yml` file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view AndroidManifest.xml from APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191762/how-to-view-androidmanifest-xml-from-apk-file)

Comment: also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8301038/5993410)

Comment: @AtefHares I want to know how the Android system know this with the AndroidManifest.xml does not contains the information(at least in the decompiled files not same as the information in the apktool.yml file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will print out the xmltree of the android manifest inside an apk file:

```
aapt dump xmltree file.apk AndroidManifest.xml
```

Sample output:

```
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  E: manifest (line=17)
    A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x7
    A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="2.1-update1" (Raw: "2.1-update1")
    A: package="com.android.spare_parts" (Raw: "com.android.spare_parts")
    E: uses-sdk (line=0)
      A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x7
      A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x7
    E: uses-permission (line=19)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE" (Raw: "android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE")
    E: uses-permission (line=20)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" (Raw: "android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION")
    E: uses-permission (line=21)
      A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS")
    E: application (line=23)
      A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f060000
      A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f020000
      E: activity (line=26)
        A: android:name(0x01010003)="SpareParts" (Raw: "SpareParts")
        E: intent-filter (line=27)
          E: action (line=28)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
          E: category (line=29)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" (Raw: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT")
          E: category (line=30)
            A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
```

Here, you can see on lines 7 and 8 the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. [Source](http://elinux.org/Android_aapt#xmltree)

Answer (score 1):

`AndroidManifest.xml` files containts those values:

`minSdkVersion`
`targetSdkVersion`

https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Use apktool to decode your APK-file.

Comment: @AtefHares Ok. But it stores inside this file new values. Android OS detectes supported versions by parsing this file.

Comment: @AtefHares After I decompile I can't find neither minSdkVersion nor targetSdkVerion, but platformBuildVersionCode and platformBuildVersionName, but they are not consistent with the sdk info in apktool.yml.

Answer (score -1):

You can find it in your app / main module level `build.gradle` file.

In below section

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "yourApplicationPackage"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

**minSdkVersion 14**

**targetSdkVersion 23**

Comment: OP is asking how to extract the info from an apk file.

Comment: Sorry, I mean where can Android find the information in the apk that installed.

Comment: OK. Thank you for acknowledge it.