# Why does android APK not record compileSdkVersion?

Tags: android

By the answer of this link 
[Android: How to find which platform version an APK targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300822/android-how-to-find-which-platform-version-an-apk-targets)

We can get these info by using aapt

- android:minSdkVersion
- android:targetSdkVersion

But **not compileSdkVersion included**.

Does it mean compileSdkVersion of a APK is not useful

for Android OS while doing installation or execution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **CompileSdkVersion** is not included in APK because it is just for compile time to understand which APIs should be used.

**minSdkVersion** is used in order to understand on which devices it can be installed, while **targetSdkVersion** is used to specify how the OS should handle the application in terms of available features and, in general, should be the most recent SDK as possible.
So MinSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are instead meant for installation/execution time, that's why you have them in the APK.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does android APK not record compileSdkVersion?

min, max and target SDK version are part of the APK manifest metadata in the [uses-sdk element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element). There's no slot for compile SDK in the manifest.

> Does it mean compileSdkVersion of a APK is not useful for Android OS while doing installation or execution?

What use would it have? APK manifest metadata is needed for determining compatibility at install time. Compile SDK version does not affect compatibility at install time, only at compile time.